# java unchecked cast required: Class<A> found: Class<CAP#1> where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to get rid of all my compiler warnings in my code, and this one is a little frustrating.

I need to do some functional operations with the `Class` object of a particular class that I've created. Let's illustrate with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = getObj();
    Class<A> clazz = obj.getClass();
}

static class A {}

static A getObj() {
    return new A();
}
```

This code throws a compiler error:

```
incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<A>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends A from capture of ? extends A
```

Ok, so I cast the `obj` from `getClass()`:

```
Class<A> clazz = (Class<A>)obj.getClass();
```

And I get this **warning** (better than an error):

```
[unchecked] unchecked cast
  required: Class<A>
  found:    Class<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends A from capture of ? extends A
```

So, how do you check the class cast?

Tried this:

```
Class c = obj.getClass();
Class<A> clazz = c instanceof Class<A> ? (Class<A>)c : null;
```

But that produced a warning AND an error.

So now I'm stumped.

Comment: `Class<? extends A> c = obj.getClass();` ? What are you _actually_ trying to get out of this? Are you just trying out generics?

Comment: That worked, awesome. Thanks. Leave an answer and I'll checkmark it.

Comment: No, not just trying out generics. I've been using them for years but sometimes they still confuse me. Ok, I will tell you my real application but you have to promise not to judge me. I have an abstract class with several classes extending it, but I keep a HashMap of the instances of the class for a singleton interface that will see if an instance of that class already exists. I've been using it for years, works great (but this warning has always been there so I wanted to get rid of the warning).

Comment: Just to help you: the solution was just there, waiting for you to find it, in the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29: *The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:

Number n = 0;
Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();*

Comment: Thank you. For what it's worth, use of `?` and `T` in examples/samples/docs has always confused me. This Q/A helped a lot.